# Is there a way to recognize the visit from user's iphone and automatically adjust web page to fit iPhone screen size?

Tags: iphone

I wonder if there is a way to recognize the visit from user's iphone and automatically adjust web page to fit iPhone screen size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$isIphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
if ($isIphone == true)  { echo 'Code You Want To Execute'; }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that rather than basing it on the UA, often a screen size query is better. I have used this before in my `head`.

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iPhone.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user+agent+mobile) a way. `User-Agent` HTTP header is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can do User-Agent detection and make changes based on seeing the "iPhone" or "iPod" string, but you can also [use a meta tag that is specifically for this purpose](http://www.engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/2008/06/19/tutorial-building-a-website-for-the-iphone/).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

Here's another good resource for information on [building an iPhone-ready website](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-useful-code-snippets-to-develop-iphone-friendly-websites).